# LED PCB through-board connectors - how to search for them?

Tags: led, pcb, connector

I have been looking for a through-board connector solution for single layer MCPCB LED boards for a while.

Some options are edge connectors or right angle male/female connector sets.
But these either don't have the correct current rating or are just too costly.

Generic bottom entry surface mount female headers don't have slightly angled pins (like your regular SOIC ICs) for avoiding shorts with the milled cutout below.

So while scrolling Google, it seems that LIFX has it all figured out when it comes to cheap and simple mass production connectors.

I added some pictures of connectors from teardowns (not mine), but can't seem to find any part# or source for them.

If anyone knows some magic buzzwords to search for or even better a part#, please tell me.

[image: Example photo 1]

[image: Example photo 2]

And another variant with a pass-through for a WiFi antenna to stick out.

[image: Example photo 3]

[image: Example photo 4]

Comment: Does this fit your bill? https://www.samtec.com/connectors/micro-pitch-board-to-board/050/strips#features

Comment: `low profile board to board connector` or `low profile mezzanine connector`